# Result not getting displayed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

Class

```
public class CL_1103_AccSobject {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String createacc(Account ac){
        String Res;
        try{
            insert ac;
            Res='Good';
        }
        catch(exception e){
            Res=e.getMessage();
        }
        Return Res;
    }

}
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="CL_1103_AccSobject">
    <aura:attribute type="Account" name="acc" default="{sObjectType:'Account'}"/>
    <lightning:card title="Account Creation" iconName="standard:account">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="create" onclick="{!c.saveme}"/>
        </aura:set>
        <lightning:input label="Account Name" value="{!v.acc.Name}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Account Phone" value="{!v.acc.Phone}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Account Fax" value="{!v.acc.Fax}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Account Industry" value="{!v.acc.Industry}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Account Rating" value="{!v.acc.Rating}"/>
        <lightning:input label="Account Result" value="{!v.res}"/>
        
    </lightning:card>
    
</aura:component>
```

controller

```
({
    saveme : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var accnt=component.get("v.acc");
        
        var action=component.get("c.createacc");
        
        action.setParams({"ac":accnt});
        
        action.setCallback(this,function(RS){
            var st=RS.getState();
            var Result=RS.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.res",Result);
            
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        
    }
})
```

application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:LC_1103_AccSobject/>
    
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is attempting to set the value of an attribute `v.res`, but this attribute does not exist. You must declare it in your Aura component.

Additionally, you've bound the value of this attribute to an input field component, which is probably not what you want. You may have wanted to simply show the value in your component (`{!v.res}`) or use a component like [`<lightning:formattedText>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedText/example).

---

As an aside, Aura is an obsolete framework. Unless you have a very specific platform limitation that requires you to build an Aura component, consider building a Lightning Web Component instead.

Note also that the [`<lightning:recordEditForm>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) component, available in both Aura and LWC, provides this record-create functionality out of the box.